# Get contact that have email or phone number with unique results

Tags: android, email, distinct, android-contacts, phone-number

I am trying to make a list of contacts that have email, phone or both.
For this purpose I am using `ContentResolver` with URI set to `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` and I select by these conditions:

```
String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "<>'' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" + " AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)";
String[] SELECTION_ARGS = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
```

I am interested only in Name of such contact. But because Data table holds each information for given contact at separate row, the resulted cursor has duplicate entries in it.

Is there any way how to DISTINCT those entries? I am using `CursorLoaderManager` with `CursorAdapter` (maybe only way is to filter them out when loader finishes?).

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315203/android-distinct-and-groupby-in-contentresolver), it's a bit old but might be helpful.

Comment: I've tried it all but unfortunately nothing helps due to those "hacks" were fixed in latest android versions or they don't work with contact content providers :/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };
    String order = "CASE WHEN " 
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, " 
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.NUMBER
            + ", " 
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
            + " COLLATE NOCASE";
    String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
```

Comment: ContactsContract.Contacts.NUMBER doesn't exists. Do you mean ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER?

Comment: But still, this will not exclude duplicate entries from select result.