# How to use distinct query in Android ContentResolver for displaying image folder

Tags: android, image, android-contentprovider

I need a distinct query for Album wise image and video display, like gallery in Android. I attached my source code below. My problem is that I'm getting repeated folder names displaying. How can I use a distinct query in this code?

```
String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {"DISTINCT "+ ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
                ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                ImageColumns.DATA }; 
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION_BUCKET,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",new String[] {"%" + "MidasOnline/Images_UserID_95"+fname+"" + "%"}, null);`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add GROUPBY in selection for DISTINCT to work

```
ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID+" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY ("+ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID
```

[more info at this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301304/1798737)

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
String[] projection= { "DISTINCT _id", "DISTINCT address"};

Cursor address =  getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null,"address ASC");
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't work! results in an exception for contentresolver!

Comment: This results in an exception in the content resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61233370/1785516).

```
val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val projection = arrayOf(
    "DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
)
val groupBySelection = " 1) GROUP BY (${MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID}"
contentResolver.query(
    uri,
    projection,
    null,
    groupBySelection,
    null,
    null
)
```