# How to GROUP BY when using a Content Provider?

Tags: android, sql, group-by, cursor, android-contentprovider

I have made a content provider for my application. For the sake of simplicity, I shall use an example. I have a table 'OrderDetails'.

1. I have a column for the OrderId.
2. I have a column for the quantity of the different product types that was purchased in that OrderId.
3. I have an OrderDetailId that is the primary key for the table.

Here is the table: [image]

I want to write the query: `SELECT OrderID, sum(quantity) FROM OrderDetails GROUP BY OrderID` Which would return this: [image]

However, I have tried to insert my GROUP BY clause in my URI for my content Provider but It will not work, so the resulting query becomes: `SELECT OrderID, sum(quantity) FROM OrderDetails` that returns this (the entire quanity of everything and the last OrderId):[image]

Here is the method to get the cursor and simply print out the result that I have just made:

```
private void findQuantityByOrder(){
    Uri uri = DatabaseContract.CONTENT_URI_ORDER_DETAILS;
    String[] selection = new String[] {DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.ORDER_ID,
            "sum("+ DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.QUANTITY + ")"
                    +"GROUP BY(" + DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.ORDER_ID + ")"};
    String projection = null;
    String sortBy = null;
    String[] args = null;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            selection,
            projection,
            args,
            sortBy);

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i ++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int orderID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("orderID"));
        int quantity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("sum(quantity)"));

        System.out.println("orderId: " + orderID + ". Quanitity: " + quantity);
    }
}
```

It only prints out the entire sum of all orders, with the last ID that was on the table.

I believe that GROUP BY was removed and no longer supported. Is there any other way that will provide the same result?

Thank you

Comment: what do you see if you output the variable named selection?

Answer (score 2):

> I have made a content provider for my application

Unless you plan on having several apps all use this data, I do not recommend implementing a `ContentProvider`.

> I believe that GROUP BY was removed and no longer supported

The `ContentProvider`/`ContentResolver` protocol does not support SQL in general, let alone `GROUP BY`. After all, there is no requirement that a `ContentProvider` be implemented using a SQL database.

> Is there any other way that will provide the same result?

Implement the `GROUP BY` on the `ContentProvider`, not on the client. IOW, handle this the same way that you would with a REST-style Web service, where it is the Web service, not the client of the Web service, that implements the SQL.

For example, if a `Uri` with a path of `/foo` handles basic queries, `/foo/summary` might implement the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` bits.

> I have tried to insert my GROUP BY clause in my URI for my content Provider but It will not work

Since we do not have your `ContentProvider` implementation, we cannot really comment on that. However, please note that `GROUP BY` is not something that you return, and so putting it in the projection would be an atypical choice.

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure if you are still looking for an answer, but, a hack for `GROUP BY` with Content Provider is to embed `group by` clause in the `URI` as a query parameter and read that in query method of the content provider.

So a Typical Query can look like

```
Uri uri = DatabaseContract.CONTENT_URI_ORDER_DETAILS + "?groupBy=" + DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.ORDER_ID;
```

The whole Thing can look like this:

```
private void findQuantityByOrder(){
    Uri uri = DatabaseContract.CONTENT_URI_ORDER_DETAILS + "?groupBy=" + DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.ORDER_ID;
    String[] projection = new String[] {DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.ORDER_ID,
            "sum("+ DatabaseContract.DatabaseOrderDetails.QUANTITY + ")"};
    String selection = null;
    String sortBy = null;
    String[] args = null;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            projection,
            selection,
            args,
            sortBy);

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i ++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int orderID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("orderID"));
        int quantity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("sum(quantity)"));

        System.out.println("orderId: " + orderID + ". Quanitity: " + quantity);
    }
}
```

And in your content provider code you can get hold of group by as easily as this,

```
String groupBy = uri.getQueryParameter("groupBy");
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question:

There are answers out there on Stackoverflow - [Android: Distinct and GroupBy in ContentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315203/android-distinct-and-groupby-in-contentresolver)
I will leave this question up because some thought has been put into the responses.

Whilst I feel that, as described in other answers, this should be sorted in the Content Provider itself. However, there is a quick fix to be had when you are calling your Content Provider:

In your Projection String you can simply add...

```
 String projection = COLUMN_NAME + "'a_condition' GROUP BY " + COLUMN_NAME"
```

Hope this helps